# Call JavaScript function after page completely loads

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a JavaScript function after load...like totally after the page loads. It's part of a chatroom I'm designing, in which a cron repeatedly checks for new data, and if there's new data, it tells the chatroom `index.php` that there's new data. The page then prints some javascript, but the page has already loaded. How do I call the functions and lines of execution after the page has loaded? Thanks so much in advance!

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
if($connection) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `refresh` WHERE `refresh`=1;";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_fields($query);
    if($result !== null) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            refreshChat();
            $.ajax({url: "chat.log", type: "POST"})
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#chattxt").html(data);
            });
        </script>           
<?php
                }
            }
//More code irrelevant to this problem.
```

The JavaScript function `refreshChat()` is simply the same code I put after the call to it. I have also tried heredoc, and it didn't work either.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 1):

You want the `window.load()` event. Here's a jQuery example;

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    // page loaded, do stuff
});
```

You could also call this on a specific tag (`<body>`, for example) as `onload=""`.

```
<body onload="...">
```

Comment: I have researched stuff and seen that. That won't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ooohh, now that you added your code it's clearer; asynchronous queries don't *wait*, they are designed that way. However, see... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Comment: Yes, I know they are designed that way, but this is added to page after load, and it never executes. I need a way to fix that. Thanks again, but not quite what I need.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // DOM Loaded
});
```

JavaScript

```
document.onload = function() {
  // DOM loaded
};
```

Comment: I know about both, and neither will do. It's for a chat, so this is the way I am retrieving new chat messges.

Answer (score 0):

After sitting on the problem and thinking about it, I realized that what I was trying to do won't work. The PHP is translated before the page is loaded on the screen at the server, and then after it loads, nothing else can happen. I need to move this over to the client and to JavaScript. Thanks though, and sorry for posting an impossible question!